# Does the controller name have to match the file name in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have tried putting the controller name different from the actual control filename and my page doesnt work. But once i put the same name for both it works. is there a way around this?

ps , i have new to codeigniter

Comment: Why do you want to get around this? If you want a URL different than the controller name, you can do that by modifying your `config/routes.php` file (or using other custom routing).

Comment: i name my controllers as controller_somename.php and dont want to show that information to the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they have to be the same, that's one of the main concepts of CodeIgniter. See more info about the controllers [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html).